# Cant build ios project, no such module or this SDK is not supported by compiler

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, sentry, swift-package-manager

So I got an demo ios project from different company but I can't launch it
Basically i get two errors:
[image]

Sometimes I also go an unsupported swift architecure error

I work on M2 processor and use XCode 14.2

Project does not have pods, all packages are managed via spm (that's what I was told)
For now i tried:

- opening xcode via rosetta (nothing changed)
- changing version of xcode to 14.0 (nothing changed)
- using other swift version via toolchain (Swift 5.7), screen below ( get different erorrs but i dont think its a good way)
  [image]

**UPDATE**

I downloaded version 14.0 of xcode and toolchain 5.7.2
When i use that version of xcode i get an error about missing classes from that sdk in scope and also some weird error from SentrySamplingProvider ( screens below)

[image]

Comment: If you have installed toolchain 5.7, whats the problem to install 5.7.2?

Comment: It tells you that SDK was built with XCode 14.0, and the developers of SDK didn't set the proper build settings to make build universal, so you now need to use XCode 14.0 to use that SDK, or obtain a new version of SDK that supports XCode 14.2

Comment: Thanks for fast reply!
I tried both of your solutions but Unfortunately it didin't work

Comment: Which sentry-cocoa version are you using @aleksanderfrnczak? We enabled BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION with 8.1.0 https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-cocoa/pull/2636, which could fix your issue.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I tried upgrading sentry-cocoa as well as adding BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION but the problem still persists]